# Proper Flex 3 control (example would be great too) to display dynamic array

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3

I need to display a table represented by the 2-dimensional array object (typed Object), with column headers and row headers coming from two separate Array objects.  Size of the Array objects containing headers is different, and can vary, size of the 2-dimensional data also varies.

DataGrid allows to show columns with headers, but I would have to specify number of columns.
Is where a control that would allow to display such a data set?

Flex 3.2, for IE 8

```
        [Bindable]
        private static var _horizontalCodes:Array;
        [Bindable]
        private static var _verticalCodes:Array;

        [Bindable]
        private var stats:Object;

        private function initStats():void {
            stats = new Object();
            for each (var colHeader:String in _horizontalCodes) {
                stats[colHeader] = new Object();
                for each (var verHeader:String in _verticalCodes) {
                    stats[colHeader][verHeader] = 0;
                }
                stats[colHeader]["total"] = 0;
            }
        }
```